# User-friendly approach for network streaming, playing and seeking of audio files in Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: cocoa, macos, audio, networking, streaming

Please advise a combination of server and client technologies, tools and frameworks to implement a solution that meets the following requirements?

File server in the network has a huge library of *mp3/aac/aiff/wav* music files

Desktop cocoa application accesses audio files using URLs: *rtmp, http, rtsp+rtp, ftp* — how to make a choice?

Audio content should be **streamed** and played with **seeking** (it's crucial) without downloading the entire file: *QuckTime, AudioQueue, AudioFile, AudioStream, CFHTTP, All of them?* — how to develop a client?

After solid research I've ended up with myriads of options and articles. But it looks like a half of them is quite out-of-date (2001—2005), and the other half is about universal code (pure C) for Mac OS X and iPhone OS.

However the main goal here is to write a Desktop music player for Mac OS 10.5.
I cannot believe that all this raw C-coding is just required.
No wrappers? No handy libraries? No components?

P. S. Research has resulted in the following combination: [qt_tools](http://omino.com/sw/qt_tools/) for hinting + [DSS](http://dss.macosforge.org/) for RTSP streaming + [QTMovie](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for playing back + [setCurrentTime:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002391-DontLinkElementID_3) for seeking. This selection requires double-space for storing hinted .MOV-versions of every music file but works anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I believe you can use `[QTMovie movieWithURL:url error:err]` to stream a movie from a URL, then pass it to a QTMovieView object. QuickTime treats audio like movies, so it may work. Or it may try to load the entire file.

Comment: Closer, but we need an extra-lightweight client (let's imagine if a person listens to an audio-book). So downloading of the entire audio file is not a case.
Any ideas about server-side support are highly appreciated. Mac OS X Server looks promising, but it's quite expensive. We must be sure it allows to stream pure audio files.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Check out http://developer.apple.com/opensource/server/streaming/index.html. It's free and I think you can get it to work under Linux.

Comment: Yes, we've selected exactly this server solution to stream music tracks. Most likely there is no way to stream and seek audio without wrapping it into hinted movies.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [QuickTime streaming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/RM/Streaming/StreamingClient/A-Intro/1Introduction.html)

Comment: Sure I did :) And it seems that this method requires back-end support by the hint tracks from the server side. But as I mentioned in the question, we have about 1 TB (!) of content.  It's just impossible to handle every one track to wrap in into .MOV-file. Or did I miss something? We need kind of ‘pure’ audio streaming. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) as a streaming solution?

Comment: Thanks for such a useful solution. Unfortunately, it looks like there is no ability to stream MP3 files without decompressing them into video format before. In this case, we still need to convert all content before streaming.